# How can i get change the input text color of components that are not related each other?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components, react-context

i'm having this issue with my components, the thing is that i'm using at this moment 3 main components, one is called Page.jsx the other is called Pencil.jsx and the other is PencilCase.js.

This is my Page.jsx component

```
import {  useState } from "react"
import { toPng } from "html-to-image"
import download from "downloadjs"


const Page = () => {


   //localStorage use it with te xt
   const [inputText, setText] = useState(
      window.localStorage.getItem('inputText')
   )
   function setLocalStorage(value) {
      try {
         setText(value)
         window.localStorage.setItem("inputText", value)
         console.log(value)
      } catch (error) {
         console.log(error)
      }
   }

   //localStorage use it with title
   const [inputTitle, setTitle] = useState(
      window.localStorage.getItem('inputTitle')
   )
   function setTitleStorage(value) {
      try {
         setTitle(value)
         window.localStorage.setItem('inputTitle', value) //(key,var)
      } catch (error) {
         console.log(error)
      }
   }

    const pngDownload = document.querySelector('.MainPage');
    function btnDownload(){
      toPng(pngDownload)
      .then(dataPng =>{
         download(dataPng, 'NotePad.png')
      })
      .catch(error=>console.log(error))
    }

   return (
      <>
         <section className="MainPage">
            <main id="MainContent">
               <header id="HeaderPage">
                  <input
                     type="text"
                     id="inputTitle"
                     placeholder="Insert Title"
                     value={inputTitle}
                     onChange={e => setTitleStorage(e.target.value)}
                     style={{color: `${inputText}`}}
                  />
                  <h2 id="TextTitle">
                     {inputTitle}
                  </h2>
               </header>
               <section className="TextContainer">

                  <textarea

                     placeholder="Insert Text"
                     name="textarea"
                     id="InputText"
                     onChange={e => setLocalStorage(e.target.value)}
                     value={inputText}
                     style={{color: `${inputText}`}}
                     >
                  </textarea>
                  <p
                     className="ShowText">
                     {inputText}
                  </p>
               </section>
            </main>
            

         </section>
         <button
               id="btnDownload"
               onClick={btnDownload}
            >
               <picture id="PrintContainer">
               <img id="PrintIcon"
                src="print-solid.svg"
                alt="Print Icon" />
               </picture>
               Print
            </button>
      </>
   )
}
export default Page
```

I was trying to set up the text color from me PencilCase.js component.

This is my PencilCase component:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import Pencil from "./Pencil"
import colors from "../../common/colors.js"


const PencilCase = () => {
    const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false)
    const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState(null);
    /*
  Create useState to passing the color from pencil to pencilCase

*/
    const handleColorClick = (color) => {
        setSelectedColor(color);
        // Save the selected color in local storage
        localStorage.setItem("inputText", color);
        console.log(selectedColor)
    };


    function handleOpen() {
        setExpand(
            prevValue => !prevValue
        )
    }


    return (
        <article id="PencilCaseContainer">
            <section
                onClick={handleOpen}
                id="ShowColor"
            >
                <picture
                    id="PaletteContainer">
                    <figure
                        id="ColorPalleteBehind">
                    </figure>
                    {/* <figure id="ColorPallete">*/}
                    <img
                        id="PaletteIcon"
                        src="palette-solid.svg"
                        alt="Palette Icon" />
                    {/*</figure>*/}
                </picture>
            </section>
            {expand &&
                <section
                    id="PencilCase">
                    <Pencil
                        colors={colors.black}
                        onClick={() => handleColorClick(colors.black)}
                    />
                    <Pencil
                        colors={colors.green}
                        onClick={() => handleColorClick(colors.green)}
                    />
                    <Pencil
                        colors={colors.yellow}
                        onClick={() => handleColorClick(colors.yellow)}
                    />
                    <Pencil
                        colors={colors.blue}
                        onClick={() => handleColorClick(colors.blue)}
                    />
                    <Pencil
                        colors={colors.red}
                        onClick={() => handleColorClick(colors.red)}
                    />
                </section>}
        </article>
    )
}

export default PencilCase
```

As you can see i'v been trying to pass the seleceted color from my PencilCase component to Page component, the thing is both of them are not related.

`<Pencil />` is child component of `<PencilCase />` so that is why i can set the props but with Page.jsx i can not do it because neither of them are children.

This is my other component where you can see the components relation

```
import Page from "./Page"
import PencilCase from "./PencilCase"


const NotePad= ()=>{

    return(
        <>
          <main className="BodyPad">
            <Page />
            <PencilCase />
          </main>
        </>
    )
}

export default NotePad
```

Pls guys help me :c

I'v been trying to create a onClick function so anytime a `<Pencil />` component is clicked the color can be saved as localStorage color and i can use it in `<Page />` component to set the textColor but it is not working, i have been reading about it and i tried do it with context and provider but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems the problem is `inputText` state on the Parent doesn't rerender, hence it's not setting the color, AFAIK it's expected behaviour. To make `input` color change and set the value to localStorage, there are two things you can do:

**1. Lifting state up to the parent**

```
const NotePad = () => {
  const [inputColor, setInputColor] = useState()

  return (
    <main>
      <Page inputColor={inputColor}/>
      <PencilCase onChangeInputColor={(color) => setInputColor(color)}/>
    </main>
  )
}

const Page = ({inputColor}) => {
  return (
    <input style={{color: `${inputColor}`}} />
  )
}

const PencilCase = ({onChangeInputColor}) => {
  return (
   <>
    <Pencil onClick={() => onChangeInputColor(colors.black)}
   <>
  )
}
```

**2. Share state using context**

```
import * as React from "react";

const InputColor = React.createContext<{
  inputColor: string | null;
  setInputColor: (color: string | null) => void;
}>({} as any);

const useInputColor = () => React.useContext(InputColor);

const ColorProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [inputColor, setInputColor] = React.useState<string | null>(null);

  return (
    <InputColor.Provider value={{ inputColor, setInputColor }}>
      {children}
    </InputColor.Provider>
  );
};

export const Context = () => {
  return (
    <ColorProvider>
      <div>
        <h3>Context</h3>
        <Page />
        <PencilCase />
      </div>
    </ColorProvider>
  );
};


const Page = () => {
  const { inputColor } = useInputColor();
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        defaultValue="Context"
        style={inputColor ? { color: inputColor } : {}}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const PencilCase = () => {
  const { setInputColor } = useInputColor();
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: 10 }}>
      <Pencil bgColor="red" onClick={() => setInputColor("red")} />
      <Pencil bgColor="white" onClick={() => setInputColor("white")} />
      <Pencil bgColor="blue" onClick={() => setInputColor("blue")} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here's for the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/share-state-fwx6gy?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uop0007356hhwb2mgk4%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uon0002356hngmz3qd8%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uoo0004356hb28ngshf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uoo0006356hewx1y8w7%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrbv6uon0002356hngmz3qd8%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uom0001356hcvo57435%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uon0002356hngmz3qd8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uom0001356hcvo57435%2522%257D%252C%2522clrbv6uoo0006356hewx1y8w7%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uoo0005356hujpwx9hz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uoo0006356hewx1y8w7%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uoo0005356hujpwx9hz%2522%257D%252C%2522clrbv6uoo0004356hb28ngshf%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uoo0003356h3wdy64o6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uoo0004356hb28ngshf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrbv6uoo0003356h3wdy64o6%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

**References:**

- https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components
- https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context

Comment: Hi fam, thank you so much for you feedback. I did the  first one `Lifting state up to the parent` and it didn't work but i noticed something weird with the color so i place a console.log to see what was the issue and then i saw it, the onClick event it wasn't working in the <PencilCase /> component but <Pencil /> component, so i passed  ` onChangeInputColor={onChangeInputColor}` to the Child component (Pencil) and inside pencil i place onClick={()=>onChangeInputColor(colors) and it worked. Thank you for your help next time i will do it like a context as the same as you answer me. <3